# React state infinite loading while using react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-grid-layout

I am using [react-grid-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout) for my learning and implemented a simple example. Based on the documentation, we'll get the updated layout values on `onLayoutChange` function and getting the below error

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I have written my code like this.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

export default function App() {
  const [generatedLayouts, setGeneratedLayouts] = useState({
    lg: [
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing", w: 8, x: 0, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 1", w: 8, x: 4, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 2", w: 8, x: 8, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 3", w: 8, x: 0, y: 4 }
    ],
    md: [
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing", w: 8, x: 0, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 1", w: 8, x: 4, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 2", w: 8, x: 8, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 3", w: 8, x: 0, y: 4 }
    ],
    sm: [
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing", w: 8, x: 0, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 1", w: 8, x: 4, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 2", w: 8, x: 8, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 3", w: 8, x: 0, y: 4 }
    ],
    xs: [
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing", w: 8, x: 0, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 1", w: 8, x: 4, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 2", w: 8, x: 8, y: 0 },
      { h: 2.9, i: "Testing 3", w: 8, x: 0, y: 4 }
    ]
  });
  const handleLayoutChange = useCallback((layout, allLayouts) => {
    setGeneratedLayouts(allLayouts);
    // return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(layout));
  }, []);

  /* const generateDOM = () => {
    return 
  }; */

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        layouts={[]}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
        cols={{ lg: 16, md: 16, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        margin={[16, 16]}
        containerPadding={[0, 0]}
        rowHeight={100}
        onLayoutChange={handleLayoutChange}
        isResizable={false}
        isDraggable
        useCSSTransforms
        onBreakpointChange={(breakpoint) => {
          console.log("breakpoint", breakpoint);
        }}
      >
        {generatedLayouts?.lg?.map((a, i) => {
          console.log("asdsad", `${a.i} ${i}`, i);
          return (
            <div key={`${a.i} ${i}`} style={{ border: "1px green solid" }}>
              Some element {i}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I comment `onLayoutChange`, it's rendering only one time.

Attaching the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/optimistic-sid-1h7d5p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) here. I'm guessing the sandbox is taking `xs` as the breakpoints and not throwing errors but that's not showing anything on UI also. If you try to open the preview in a new tab, the breakpoints are `lg` and the state is updating infinite times.
I would be grateful if someone helps where am I missing.

Comment: What is the issue? Nothing is rendered?

Comment: Not sure. The component is loading infinite times and throwing ```Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.```

Comment: I don't see that error logged at all.

Comment: Try to open the preview in a new tab from the sandbox.

Comment: I'm guessing the sandbox is taking `xs` as the breakpoints and not throwing errors but that's not showing anything on UI also. If you try to open the UI in a new tab, the breakpoints are `lg` and the state is updating infinite times.

Comment: Yeah, I see the render looping error now. Investigating.

Comment: Is there a need/use case for using the `onLayoutChange` prop? It seems you've defined the layouts and just need to grab the current `breakpoint` from `onBreakpointChange`.

Comment: Yeah. I can change the position of the widget to another place and save the state. [Here](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/0-showcase.html) is the example from `react-grid-layout` examples

Comment: The only difference I can see between your sandbox code and the demo you linked is that the demo doesn't actually do anything with the `onLayoutChange` handler *other than* proxy the arguments through to another callback that was passed in props, and for the demo this prop is simply an [empty function body](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/0-showcase.jsx#L27). I think the issue with your sandbox is due to using an `onLayoutChange` handler that updates some local state.